# How do I add "| null" to every field of an interface?

Tags: typescript

I have an inteface like this:

```
interface TrainingSession {
  date: string;
  topic: string;
}
```

I want to create a form which will send a /createTrainingSession request to my API. In this form, I'd like use the above interface to type the data structure holding the user's input.
Like:

```
const initialFormInput : TrainingSession = {
  date: null,
  topic: null
}
```

The problem is that since the initial interface requires a string in both fields, I can't pass `null` there. One solution that comes to mind is extending the interface with `null` like so:

```
interface FormTrainingSession extends TrainingSession {
  date: string | null;
  topic: string | null;
}
```

But that's kind of annoying - rewriting the interface from scratch just to add null?

I like how `Partial<TrainingSession>` works, but obviously Partial adds `| undefined` to each field, rather than what I want - `| null`. Is there an equivalent of Partial, that just adds | null?

Answer (score 8):

Funnily enough, if you CTRL+click `Partial` (utility type included in TS itself) in VS Code, you'll see this:

```
/**
 * Make all properties in T optional
 */
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

Inspired by the above ....
To create a generic type that adds `| null` to each field instead, just do this:

```
export type PartialNull<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] | null;
};
```

The difference between the two are:

- lack of `?` in `PartialNull` - `?` appends `| undefiend` to the existing type, thus making the field optional - `| null` is added instead of `?`.
- the type name (obviously, since Partial already exists)

To use the new PartialNull type, import it in the .ts file you want to use it, and then write

```
const formData : PartialNull<TrainingSession> = {
  date: null,
  name: null
}
```